# Web3Modal.connect() is not a function

Tags: web3js

I am getting this error in react while using web3modal v2 library..When i click mint button it says that web3modal.connect() is not a function...can anyone help me solve this problem

```
function App() {
  const mintAnNft = async () => {
    try {
      if (window.ethereum) {
        const _provider = await Web3Modal.connect();
        const web3 = new Web3(_provider);
        const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddress);
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        const account = accounts[0];
        console.log("accont jis", account);
        await contract.methods.mint().send({ from: account });
      } else {
        alert("PLEASE INSTALL METAMASK");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("An error occurred", error);
    }
    console.log("Minted successfully");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="everything">
        <div className="connectBtn">
          <div className="btn">
            <WagmiConfig config={wagmiConfig}>
              <HomePage />
            </WagmiConfig>
          </div>
        </div>

        <Web3Modal
          projectId={projectId}
          ethereumClient={ethereumClient}
          themeVariables={{
            "--w3m-font-family": "sans-serif",
            "--w3m-background-color": "rgb(245, 222, 179)",
            "--w3m-accent-color": "#f5deb3",
            "--w3m-button-border-radius": "50px",
          }}
        />
        <div className="content">
          <img src={imgSource} alt="" className="image" />
          <button className="nftMint" onClick={mintAnNft}>
            Mint
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```